# Configuring irssi to indent a specified amount when wrapping a message

Tags: themes, irssi, xmpp

I use irssi-plugin-xmpp with transports to other instant messaging protocols, so JIDs get pretty long, meaning that messages that get sent to me get squished to the right side of the window.  I would like to have irssi indent messages by a fixed amount when wrapping, instead of indenting based on how long the users nick is.  How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not yet have a file named `~/.irssi/default.theme`, do

`cp /usr/share/irssi/themes/default.theme ~/.irssi/`

You might have to set this as your theme by doing the following in irssi:

`/set theme default`

But I didn't, `default.theme` is already set as my theme, probably because I have made changes to it with other commands.  If you already know which theme you are using, is it instead of `default.theme` below.

Now open the file `~/.irssi/default.theme` in your favorite text editor, and change this line:

`msgnick = "%K<%n$0$1-%K>%n %|";`

to look like this:

`msgnick = "%K<%n$0$1-%K>%n ";`

If you are using some other theme, your `msgnick` might be different.  The important part is the `%|`, as is ( kind of ) explained at this link:  http://www.irssi.org/documentation/startup

Now start irssi and type:

`/set indent=10`

replacing `10` with whatever amount of indentation you want.

Don't forget to save:

`/save`